# Is there a way to do a capacitor svelte app without it being a static site?

Tags: ionic-framework, svelte, sveltekit, capacitor

I am trying to create a random image generator using svelte and capacitor, I'm using server side rendering to render the first image when the page is first loaded and to port my svelte site to capacitor I had to make it a static site using [static-adapter](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-static) and setting prerender to true. The problem is that since the site is staticaly generated the first time the page loads it always displays the same image instead of it being random.

This is my file structure:

```
|---src/
    |---routes/
        |---+page.svelte
        |---+page.server.ts
```

On the client side I'm simply rendering the image returned by the load function from the server side, here's the code:

```html
<script>
  export let data
<\script>

<img src={data.imageURL}/>
```

This is the code in the server file:

```js
export const prerender = true;

export async function load() {
  let imageURL = await getRandomImageUrl()
  return { imageURL }
}
```

It's a simple single page app, I don't have any routes other than the home page. As you can see I'm just fetching a random image url from an API on the server, since the app is pre-rendered this API call happenes on build time instead of happening when the page first loads

I could probably pull the first image on mount instead of doing **SSR**, but I wan't to know if there is a way to do it the way I'm trying to.

Thanks to anyone who can help

Comment: There are obviously ways to solve this. Attach some code, so that we can figure out which solution fits best for your case.

Comment: You can pre-render dynamic routes (e.g. /[id])  when using `static adapter`. You'll however have to define you prerendered routes in `entries` inside your `svelte.config.js`. Kindly attach your code and file structure.

Comment: @NatumanyaGuy I just updated my question